# Trying to use openFB with Cordova

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova, oauth

So i´m having a situation that someone might be able to help.

Im creating a Mobile APP using PhoneGap Build. I´m trying to use this http://coenraets.org/blog/2014/04/facebook-phonegap-cordova-without-plugin/

Right know if I open the app inBrowser it will work. Ask's for permissions etc and fetch the user data correctly. Of course I defined a Valid oAuth: localhost/...html.

So it works for browser but doesnt work for mobile. Wich should be, if so, the valid url for the mobile? Cause since it's an APP iºm confused. I dont think it's necessary show code but if so just ask me.

[image: Developers area]
[image: Permissions working fine]

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can still use openFB and it will work. you don't even need to change anything in the openfb.js file. all you have to do is manipulate the call method from the page where you want to call the facebook login window.

say for example you have the facebook call method in index.html 
then add this script to that index.html page where the function "**facebooklogin()**" is called

```js
<script>
openFB.init({ appId: 'your-app-id' });
function facebooklogin() {
    openFB.login(function (response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                openFB.api({
                    path: "/{your app version in facebook developer envi.}/me?",
                    params: { "access_token": accessToken, "?fields":"name,email,gender,user_birthday,locale,bio&access_token='"+accessToken+"'" },
                    success: function (response) {
                        var data = JSON.stringify(response);
                       // do whatever you want with the data for example
                       $(".data_div").html(data); 
                       $(".data_email").html(data.email);

                    },
                    error: function(err){
                    alert(err);
                   }
                });
            }
            else { 
                   alert(“empty response returned”);

            }
        }
        else { 
                alert(“not connected”);
        }
    },
    {
        scope: "public_profile,email,user_birthday"
    });
}
</script>
```

very important! Please replace **{your app version in facebook developer envi.}** with your app version like **v2.0** or **v2.5**

also don't forget to change '**your app id**' to you facebook app id example **432046826485152**

with openfb you don't need to crack your head over learning hoe to configure facebook login in other platforms. this will serve all platforms

Answer (score 1):

I've got it working on the phone.

The weird thing is that a real URL is not necessary, just a semantic valid one. I've added a Facebook Canvas platform, on the facebook app page, and filled the platform form:

```
URL = http://localhost/www/
Secure Canvas URL = https://localhost/www/
```

Both of above domains doesn't exists. I haven't filled the "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" field in the advanced tab.

After that, I've written the following code in my app:

```
openFB.init("xyz!@#123456789"
  , "http://localhost/www/oauthcallback.html");
```

It seems that what matters is that Facebook Canvas's domains or sub domains matches the one on the openFB.init redirectURL param...

I'm using openFB version 0.1. I'm gonna test the earlier versions.

UPDATE

It just have worked because I was using `phonegap serve` and it makes openFB understand that my app is a website, because phonegap developer app is a browser wrapper, not a app wrapper. If I try to run it in a compiled app (`phonegap local build`), my code doesn't work. I think I'll have to use facebook-connect earlier than I thought...

Comment: Hi Robson. I got it working using phongap-facebook-connect its uses the mobile native functions wich is nicer. So I didn't used openFB. I would tell you to use it too. FOr that I just followed the instructions but I used the CLI not the Cloud. Cloud Build isn't very good. Now I got both working for IOS and Android. :) Anyway thanks for your reply ;) 1+

Comment: Thanks on the comment. The problem is that I haven't much time to learn both iOS and Android facebook-connect interfaces. With openFB I can handle the same behavior all over any platform, like Windows Phone. In the near future I'll have to use facebook-connect to improve user experience, but for now I'll stick with openFB :-)

Comment: Ye I understand. If everything goes well with facebook-connect it should be workinf easly on both interfaces. The only difference I noted is that to install in Android I had to run a lot of CLI commands (that I really didnt understood well what was happening) But it works flawless. :) Anyway depending on the project OpenFB it's a very good alternative.

Comment: In the end it worked just for Windows Phone. To other platforms I've used a real URL and a fix to openFB runningInCordova() function: function runningInCordova() { return window.cordova; }