# How to avoid Facebook security warning openfb Phonegap

Tags: cordova, oauth

Iam using this for connecting facebook

```
   http://coenraets.org/blog/2014/04/facebook-phonegap-cordova-without-plugin/
```

Facebook was login successful and it was struck with
Success
SECURITY WARNING: Please treat the URL above as you would your password and do not share it with anyone. See the Facebook Help Center for more information.

How to overcome with this.

Comment: Following post related...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24695913/trying-to-use-openfb-with-cordova/25777644#25777644

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install InAppBrowser plugin on phonegap/cordova:

```
phonegap plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
```

Comment: @Edru Thanks for the answer. this remains me i have to answer question even for my question. i got it worked long back with the same solution.

Comment: We don't have enough time for remembering everything and doing all we want. Thanks @JothiSankarNKanakavel